# A Test on Page Life Cycle for loading ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle

I'm trying to understand the phases of an asp.net page lifecycle by building a simple site web composed of a web form with a code behind in c#.

In the aspx page there is only a button to make a postback so I won't show the code; instead, I'll report the browser output because I use the Response.Write method to write all the page phases that I'm handling.

In the aspx.cs file I started the class with a property:

```
public string prop
{
    get
    {
        object _propViewstate = ViewState["propview"];
        if (_propViewstate != null)
        {
            return (string)_propViewstate;
        }
        else
        {
            return "Prop ViewState still not avaiable <BR> ";
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["propview"] = value;
    }
}
```

How you can see it's used to store in the ViewState a string value that I'll check in each phase. The setting of the property becomes in the method that handles the PreInit event of Page only if it's not a postback (I take advantage of AutoEventWireUp):

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("PreInit_Method <BR>");
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        prop = "PreInit";
    }
        Response.Write(prop + "<BR> <BR>");  
}
```

Then I'll override these methods of the Page to check this property in the ViewState: OnInit, OnInitComplete,  OnPreLoad, OnLoad, OnLoadComplete. The code is very similar so I'll show only the OnInit override:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Init_Method <BR>");
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        prop += " - Init";
    }
        Response.Write(prop + "<BR> <BR>");
}
```

I update the value of the property in the ViewState for each method if it's not a postback. I override also the LoadViewState method:

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    Response.Write("LoadViewState_Method <BR>");
    Response.Write("Before calling base method: ");
    Response.Write(prop);
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);
    Response.Write("After calling base method: ");
    Response.Write(prop + "<BR> <BR>");
}
```

Now I show the output before and after the postback and then finally my questions will come:

[Without PostBack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUfgG.png)

[After PostBack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb4SD.png)

My questions:

0) First of all, I'm using those methods correctly to test the loading of the ViewState? Which would be a better way to test it?

1) Before to PostBack, the property is available in all the methods. This is because I'm accessing to this viewstate's property that I just created? (If I do `Response.Write(ViewState["propview"] + "<BR> <BR>");` I got the same effect, obviously)

2) Based on my test, I could say that the ViewState is loaded in the LoadViewState method because before to call the parent's method inside it I can't see my property set but just after that call it's available.

On the net, I read that the ViewState is instead loaded on LoadPageStateFromPerstistenceMedium. In the image from the official ASP.NET Page Life Cycle, I see that LoadPageStateFromPerstistenceMedium is called before LoadViewState and with my test inside this method I checked that my property is not available before the call to `base.LoadViewState` so I would say that the ViewState is loaded in the Page's LoadViewState method, correct?

Comment: Are you locked into using Web Forms? I can understand if your job requires you to. But if you have any sort of choice, learn a more modern framework instead of wasting your time on the particulars of an old, slow, and painful one.

Comment: I know that but i'm locked on Web Forms...